# C# equivalent of Java PushbackReader's unread()

Tags: c#, java, .net

I'm looking for a C# equivalent to the Java's unread() method.

The C# equivalent to PushbackReader is supposedly System.IO.StreamReader, but StreamReader doesnt have an "unread()" equivalent. It has Peek(), but no way to put a character back onto the stream.

Java Code:

```
// putBackChar puts the character back onto the stream
// adjusts current line number if necessary
private void putBackChar()
{
    if (ch == '\n')
        currentLine--;

    try
    {
        in.unread((int) ch);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Peek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx) reads the character without popping it out of the stream so you wouldn't need to put it back onto the stream.

Comment: Yeah, that'd work. I cant really think of any other reason to push back. I'll stick with Peek(), thanks.